# WPF, MVVM, how to bind propertys dynamically?

Tags: c#, wpf, mvvm, binding

I have a question. How to bind variables dynamically from ViewModel to View? For now, it not even displayed. If i not using Command, it works great (but of course, i can bind image only once).

My **View**:

```
namespace somestuff.View
{

     public partial class WindowView : Window
     {
         public WindowView()
         {
            this.DataContext = new WindowViewModel();
            InitializeComponent();
        }
    }
}
```

my **View.Xaml** (shorten):

```
<Image Source="{Binding DisplayedImage}"/>
<Button Command="{Binding NewImageCommand}"/>
```

And my **ViewModel:**

```
public WindowViewModel()
{
    _canExecute = true;
}

public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;

private void NotifyPropertyChanged(string propertyName)
{
    PropertyChanged?.Invoke(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName));
}

public string DisplayedImage //displaying image
{
    get { return filepath; }

    set { filepath = value; NotifyPropertyChanged(nameof(filepath)); }
}

public string filepath { get; set; } //var for binding


private bool _canExecute;
private ICommand _newImageCommand; //command for button
public ICommand NewImageCommand
{
    get
    {
        return _newImageCommand ?? (_newImageCommand = new Commands.CommandHandler(() => GetImage(), _canExecute));
    }
}

public void GetImage() { filepath = Pictures.GetNewImage(); } //command on button click
```

Can you tell me, why after triggering Command `GetImage()` on button click the image binded on `Image` not changed? If i move `filepath = Pictures.GetNewImage();` from command (more clear, i not use command) all works great, but i cant re-invoke binding to my Image. Can you tell me, how to bind propertis dynamically into View from View model? When value of variable (in this case, filepath) change, i want to change View control too.

Thanks for any advices.

**EDIT:**

I have 6 `Image` Labels. I displaying images in it like that:

```
public BitmapImage DisplayedHighPerformanceImage
    {
        get { return kMMHP; }

        set { kMMHP = value; NotifyPropertyChanged(nameof(kMMHP)); }
    }
```

So i need `filepath` to init 6 diffrent bitmaps. Then i work on that bitmaps (for exampe, that `kMMHP`) So i want to display every new bitmap initialized from `kMMHP` image.

```
kMMHP = method1(); //displaying it
//other stuff do with diffrent bmps
kMMHP = method2(); //displaying it after second method with changed values
```

Comment: Just implement the DisplayedImage property correctly, with `NotifyPropertyChanged(nameof(DisplayedImage))`. Then call `DisplayedImage = Pictures.GetNewImage();`

Comment: Besides that, you shouldn't use a property as the "backing field" of another property. Just declare `private string filepath;`

Comment: Thank you @Clemens for your time. The thing isnt that simply as u mentioned.

From `filepath` i init bunch of `Bitmaps` and `BitmapImages`. Then, i work on on this bitmaps. At all i have 6 `Image` labels, 3 `bitmaps` and 3 `bitmapimages` variables. So i need that string (`filepath`) to init 6 diffrent bmp variables. Then, i displaying by binding that vars. So i cant use simple `DisplayedImg = Pictures...` because then i work on bitmaps that i initialized from `filepath`

Comment: I displaying `bitmap` like that:

`public BitmapImage DisplayedHighPerformanceImage
        {
            get { return kMMHP; }

            set { kMMHP = value; NotifyPropertyChanged(nameof(kMMHP)); }
        }`

Comment: Well, I didn't read `public BitmapImage DisplayedImage`. So the code you're showing here does not compile. Please edit it in a way that we can understand what you are trying to achieve. Posting some meta-code is pointless.

Comment: I make an edit, check it if you can please and tell me, is it now clear

Comment: and i should write `public string DisplayedImage`, not `public BitmapImage...`, my bad, i want to make code shorter for example

Answer (score 1, accepted):

NotifyPropertyChanged must be called with the name of the property, not the name of its backing field. And in order to fire the change notification event, you have to set the property, not the backing field:

```
public BitmapImage DisplayedHighPerformanceImage
{
    get { return kMMHP; }
    set { kMMHP = value; NotifyPropertyChanged(nameof(DisplayedHighPerformanceImage)); }
}

DisplayedHighPerformanceImage = method1();
```

Comment: Works great, thanks! Could you tell me, if i can every `kMMHP` values change for `DisplayedHighPerformanceImage`? Is it works as: `kMMHP == DisplayedHighPerformance...`?

Comment: Not sure what you mean exactly, but of course the value of the property and its backing field are always the same (since there is  `get { return kMMHP; }`). The backing field is however private and can't be accessed from outside the class.